# Rsync exclude with list containing full path?

Tags: linux, rsync

I am trying to use rsync with exclude parameter. But there is a problem.

firstly crated file list older than 30 min

```
find /var/log/hosts/ -type f  -mmin -30 > list.txt
```

then use it with exclude

```
rsync -arvzh --exclude-from 'list.txt'  /var/log/hosts/  root@x.x.x.x:/Archive/Rsyslog_Logs/
```

But its not working; syncs all files

```
list.txt 
/var/log/hosts/p_rsyslog/2021/05/11/14.log
/var/log/hosts/loggerarchive/2021/05/11/14.log
/var/log/hosts/node1/2021/05/11/14.log
/var/log/hosts/node2/2021/05/11/14.log
/var/log/hosts/node3/2021/05/11/14.log
...
```

Comment: I think your list.txt should not include the full paths. Try without `/var/log/hosts/`. For instance `p_rsyslog/2021/05/11/14.log`.

Answer (score 5):

The file paths in your exclude file need to be relative to your transfer root directory `/var/log/hosts/`, so the paths in `list.txt` should look like this:

```
/p_rsyslog/2021/05/11/14.log
/loggerarchive/2021/05/11/14.log
/node1/2021/05/11/14.log
/node2/2021/05/11/14.log
/node3/2021/05/11/14.log
```

Note that these paths start with a leading `/` to be considered as full paths. Without leading `/` they match against the final component of the path, e.g.
`node1/2021/05/11/14.log` would match

```
/var/log/hosts/node1/2021/05/11/14.log
```

as well as

```
/var/log/hosts/another_dir/node1/2021/05/11/14.log
```

which is probably not desired.

You could run

```
find /var/log/hosts/ -type f -mmin -30 | sed 's#^/var/log/hosts##' > list.txt
```

to remove prefix `/var/log/hosts` from each line in your exclude file.

Note that option `-r` is already included in `-a`, you may remove it in your `rsync` command.

Comment: "need to be relative to your transfer root directory" is the interesting bit to me.